# PHP Admin restriction

Tags: php

On my website I have the option to add admins but I don't have options to change their permissions, so here's what I want:

```
if (!defined("IN_SCRIPT") || !isset($_SESSION['admin_user_id']) ||
    !$_SESSION['admin_user_id'] || !isset($_SESSION['admin_username']) ||
    !$_SESSION['admin_username']) 
{
    header("Location: login.php?menu=$menu");
    die();
}
```

I have this code on the top of every page. Is there any chance that I can restrict access to admin id `1`, which is my ID, and not let others access this page.

Comment: Generally, "admin" means they have all permissions.

Comment: Yes, but if I change this code at every page to specific Admin ID they won't have access to General Settings, etc..

Comment: If someone should not have access to everything, then they should not be an "admin". Of course, without knowing anything about your setup there's no possible way to help you, but perhaps you should have different staff ranks?

Comment: I understand what you want to say, but currently I don't have ranks, only "Admins", so this is what I need, and I solved it. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((!defined("IN_SCRIPT") || !isset($_SESSION['admin_user_id']) || !$_SESSION['admin_user_id'] || !isset($_SESSION['admin_username']) || !$_SESSION['admin_username'] || $_SESSION['admin_user_id'] != '1') {
  header("Location: login.php?menu=$menu");
  die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I am not sure it will work or not. If your user id is 1 it may work.

```
if (!defined("IN_SCRIPT") || !isset($_SESSION['admin_user_id']) || !$_SESSION['admin_user_id'] || !isset($_SESSION['admin_username']) || !$_SESSION['admin_username'] || ($_SESSION['admin_user_id'] != 1)){
header("Location: login.php?menu=$menu");
die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a general set of rules to allow access and die() otherwise. If you want to add additional restricions on certain pages, the easiest bandaid fix would be to just run another if() check at whatever pages you want to block for anyone aside from you.